# Python - Trying to modify multiple variables at once by storing them in an array and iteratively "updating" them

Tags: python, arrays

To understand what I'm trying to do, first look at the code I've included below:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []

x = [a, b, c]

x[0] = [5, 10, 15]
x[1] = [30, 60, 90]
x[2] = [100, 200, 300]
```

Now, what I *wish* I could do is find a technique such that those last three lines would update the elements I had initially stored in `x` -- In other words, I *wish* that assigning a value to `x[0]` would directly update `a`, and assigning a value to `x[1]` would update `b`, and assigning a value to `x[2]` would update `c`. If this was the case, we'd be able to see the following outputs:

```
print(a)
>> [5, 10, 15]

print(b)
>> [30, 60, 90]

print(c)
>> [100, 200, 300]
```

I know this won't happen because assigning a value to `x[i]` just replaces the `ith` element in `x`, rather than "updating" the value of the `ith` element. And frankly, that makes much more sense and is obviously the way it should be. But, is there an alternate way to "update" variables in a list/array like this?

Here's a more detailed example of why I'm looking to do this:

```
dataset = 'directory\data.csv'

writer = []
director = []
runtime = []
language = []
country = []
genre = []
budget = []
year = []

features = [writer, director, runtime, language, country, genre, budget, year]

cnt = 0
for cnt in range(0,len(features)):
    with open(dataset,'r',encoding="latin1") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",quotechar='"')
        for row in reader:
            features[cnt].append(row[cnt])
        features[cnt] = np.array(features[cnt])        # <<- trying to convert each element from list to numpy array
```

In other words, I'm trying to read data from a .csv file and copy each column to one of several different lists, which I initialized between `dataset` and `features`. Then, I need to convert these lists to `numpy` arrays so that I can use the `np.where()` function, since `.index()` won't do what I need for this task.

Ideally, after the most recent snippet of code, I'd be able to see all the elements in `features` had been updated. For example, the following outputs would **ideally** be what we see after running the above code:

```
print(country)
>> ['USA', 'USA', 'UK', 'Germany', 'USA', 'Italy', ... , 'Germany']

print(language)
>> ['English', 'English', 'English', 'German', 'English', 'Italian', ... ,'German']

# etc. etc.
```

Problem is, in my actual code, I have many more lists (ie. many more .csv columns) I need to copy, so that's why I put them all in one `features` list/array. I was hoping to be able to iteratively copy a different column into each list, and then convert each list to a numpy array, all in one compact loop. This would eliminate the need for a separate loop for each column/list I want to copy. But unfortunately, I can't figure out how to "update" each `features` element rather than write something entirely different in its place.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Apologies for poor syntax/efficiency anywhere, I'm not very experienced with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do what you want.  `a`, `b`, and `c` are mutable lists, and `x` stores references to the *same* lists referenced by `a`, `b` and `c`.  Don't reassign elements of `x`, *mutate* them:

```py
a = []
b = []
c = []

x = [a, b, c]
print(f'{x=}')
print(f'{a=}')
print(f'{b=}')
print(f'{c=}')

x[0][:] = [5, 10, 15]   # replace the entire content of the list at x[0]...
x[1][:] = [30, 60, 90]
x[2][:] = [100, 200, 300]
print(f'{x=}')
print(f'{a=}')
print(f'{b=}')
print(f'{c=}')
```

```
x=[[], [], []]
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
x=[[5, 10, 15], [30, 60, 90], [100, 200, 300]]
a=[5, 10, 15]
b=[30, 60, 90]
c=[100, 200, 300]
```

`x` stores references to the lists in `a`, `b`, and `c`.  `x[0] is a` is `True`, so if you mutate `x[0]` then `a` reflects the change.  Same for the rest.

You could also `x[0].append(item)` or `x[0].extend(list_of_items)` to grow the `a` list.

But if you *reassign* `x[0]`, then `x[0]` no longer references `a`.  `x[0] = [1,2,3]` stores the reference to a new list in that location and no longer references the object `a` references.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. You are a godsend!